# Can't access to the page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeignator. it show me an error like "404 Page not found" when i browse it. below is the code

Controller Code:
**Insert.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Insertion extends CI_Controller {


    public function Insert()
    {
        $this->load->view('Insert_view');
    }
}
?>
```

View Code: **Insert_view.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make controller fiile name as `Insertion.php` instead `Insert.php`

Comment: What URL is typed?

Answer (score 0):

If your url is something like www.mywebsite.com/insertion than your controller file should be Insertion.php with class Insertion

If you like to use www.mywebsite.com/insert then your controller file should be Insert.php with class Insert and change the Insert function to index

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Insertion extends CI_Controller {

   public function index(){
     $this->load->view('insert_view');   
   }

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First **View** File Code Named (**Insertion_view.php**)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the **Controller File** Code Named (**Welcome.php**)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Model{
public function Insert()
    {
        $this->load->view('Insertion_view');
    }
```

Now write this URL in Browser
http://127.0.0.1/Welcome/insert

Here insert is the method call from **Welcome.php** and show **Insertion_view.php**

You will get 
**

---

**Hello World!!**